# Proxy issues with IM clients using yahoo

Tags: dansguardian

I've tried a number of clients now including Kopete, Pidgin and Empathy but none of them seem to respect my proxy settings. For example in Pidgin after adding a yahoo account then setting:

```
Proxy type: HTTP
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 8080
```

(I'm going to be going through Privoxy) in the `Proxy` tab then clicking `Use account proxy for HTTP and HTTPS connections` in the Advanced tab.

All I get is

```
Unable to connect: Server closed the connection
```

from Pidgin.

Everything works fine if I flush iptables of course, but I obviously don't want to do that.

How can I get at least one of these clients to work with Yahoo IM and through a proxy (local Privoxy)?

EDIT:

I discovered it was actually `Dansguardian` that was killing `Pidgin` since the blanket block `SSL` and blanket block `IP address only` were on and it seems `Pidgin` connect via some address like `https://66.196.120.xx:5050` each time.

EDIT 2:

This allowance in `Dansguardian` also fixes the problems with `telepathy` too and it also now connects and seems to respect the system/environmental proxy settings. Just Kopete then that is broken..

Comment: So does it work now? Could you clarify on that?

Comment: @MiJyn Pidgin works now yes if I allow SSL tunneling from IPs in `Dansguardian`. The other clients `Kopete` and `telepathy` do not work for me though, they seem to simply ignore the system proxy regardless of whether I set it in `~.pam_environement` , `/etc/environment` or in the system network settings. Thus they try to connect through the `iptables` blocked ports `80, 443` rather than using `dansguardian` and `privoxy` on port `8080`. Although `lsof -i -n -P` does show `Kopete` to have established a connection on `5050` it forever says connecting on the prog itself, until I flush `iptables`.

Comment: When I first try to connect to my Yahoo account through `Kopete` `lsof -i -n -P` shows `kio_http  4845  _myusername_    9u  IPv4  86989      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.102:56591->68.142.240.31:443 (SYN_SENT)` too, I have no idea what this is but it is clearly associated with `Kopete` and still trying to go through `443` despite the environment proxy settings.